# Passing data between reagent components

Tags: clojurescript, bulma, reagent, re-frame

I have the following reagent components

```
(defn comments-component [arg-id]
  [:p arg-id])

(defn arguments-component [list-of-args]
  [:ul.arguments
   (for [{:keys [comment upvotes id]} @list-of-args]
     ^{:key id}
     [:li
      [:p comment]
      [:p upvotes]
      [:p id
       [modal-button :argument
       ;title
        "Comments"
       ;body
        [:div
         [:p "Comments"]
         [comments-component id]]
        ;footer
       [:p "OpinionNeeded"] ]]])])
        

(defn debate []
  (let [debate-topic @(rf/subscribe [:debate/topic])
        debate-affirmatives (rf/subscribe [:debate/affirmatives])
        debate-negatives (rf/subscribe [:debate/negatives])]
    (fn []
      [:div
       [:a {:href "/"} "Return home"]
       [:p "This page is being worked on"]
       [:div
        [:h2 (get debate-topic :title)]
        [:p (get debate-topic :description)]]
       [:div.columns
        [:div.column.is-half
         [:p "Agree"]
         [arguments-component debate-affirmatives]]
        [:div.column.is-half
         [:p "Disagree"]
         [arguments-component debate-negatives]]]])))
```

The problem I'm encountering is that the modal button is supposed to create a modal popup with the id for each specific argument, (which I can then use to fetch the comments for that specific argument.)

But instead, I'm getting this bug whereby all the modals for different arguments show the same id.

I cannot figure out why this is happening, but it seems that all the `modal-button` functions are getting called with the id of the last or first argument to be rendered.

This is what the relevant portion of app-db looks like on this page

```
:affirmatives [{:id 1, :comment "", :upvotes 0, :topic_id 2, :affirm true} {...}]
:negatives [{:id 2, :comment "", :upvotes 0, :topic_id 2, :affirm true} {...}]
:comments [{:id 1, :comment "", :upvotes 0, :argument_id 1, :topic_id 2} {...}]
```

The :argument_id in each comment is a reference to the :id in the affirmatives/negatives

And here's the code that generates the modals.

```
(rf/reg-event-db
 :app/show-modal
 (fn [db [_ modal-id]]
  (assoc-in db [:app/active-modals modal-id] true)))

(rf/reg-event-db
 :app/hide-modal
 (fn [db [_ modal-id]]
  (update db :app/active-modals dissoc modal-id)))

(rf/reg-sub
 :app/active-modals
 (fn [db _]
  (:app/active-modals db {})))

(rf/reg-sub
 :app/modal-showing?
 :<- [:app/active-modals]
 (fn [modals [_ modal-id]]
  (get modals modal-id false)))

(defn modal-card [id title body footer]
 [:div.modal
  {:class (when @(rf/subscribe [:app/modal-showing? id]) "is-active")}
  [:div.modal-background
   {:on-click #(rf/dispatch [:app/hide-modal id])}]
  [:div.modal-card
   [:header.modal-card-head
    [:p.modal-card-title title]
    [:button.delete
     {:on-click #(rf/dispatch [:app/hide-modal id])}]]
   [:section.modal-card-body
    body]
   [:footer.modal-card-foot
    footer]]])

(defn modal-button [id title body footer]
 [:div
  [:button.button.is-primary
   {:on-click #(rf/dispatch [:app/show-modal id])}
   title]
  [modal-card id title body footer]])
```

Comment: I don't see anything obvious. Did you try printing `id` and checking if it's different for all items (without even adding any reagent code)?
Also, personally I wouldn't pass `list-of-args` as an atom, I would dereference it before passing it to arguments-component, but I don't think this could be the issue

Comment: @Xyrue I did in fact do that and it was different for every item. The problem was with the modals as someone has answered below. And thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All your modals are passed the same id `:argument`. Thus, you always show the same modal, since the db lookup in your subscription is for `:argument`.

A minor tip: Following kebap-case is the recommended style in Clojure. So your app-db attributes should probably be `argument-id` and `topic-id`.

Furthermore, I would recommend subscribing `debate-affirmatives` and `debate-negatives` inside the components you pass them to. This would make them more self-containing.